# Does the Magic stat affect all magic or only offensive spells?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

From "[The Ultimate Strategy Guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/45703)" FAQ:

> **Magic (Mag)**:
>
> Magic is used to power up the magic that a character can use. This includes summons as well as regular magic and enemy skills. The higher your Mag, the higher damage you'll hit with magic.

I can't tell if it affects healing and protection too, or just offensive spells.

**Does the Magic stat affect all magic? Or just offensive spells?**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Magic affects healing. The formula to calculate how much you heal with Cure is:

> 6 * (Magic + Level) + 22 * Power

So the higher the Magic stat, the more HP that character will heal with a given Cure spell.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/22395)

Comment: this is only a partial answer

Comment: What do you think would make the answer more complete?

Comment: the question was about all other spells rather than offensive, not just cure.

Answer (score 0):

Each type of magic has it's own formula (offensive, defensive, healing).

MAt = Magic Attack

MDf = Magic Defense

**Offensive**:

> The Magical Formula for Base Damage is defined as such:
>
> Base Damage = 6 * (MAt + Lvl)

**Defensive**:

> Ability Power and the Defense Stat are factored in at the same time,
>   just like the Physical formula:
>
> Damage = [(Power * (512 - MDf) * Base Damage) / (16 * 512)]

**Healing**:

> The Cure formula is very similar to the Magical Formula, and starts
>   off in a similar way.
>
> Base Damage = 6 * (MAt + Lvl)
>
> Damage = Base Damage + 22 * Power

Other formulas can be found in the FAQ linked in the source.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps/197341-final-fantasy-vii/faqs/22395)
(Starts at 3.4.2  Magical)